# found for DialogContentExampleDialog. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents

Tags: angular

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте хотел использовать модальное окно material в проекте Angular, но выходит ошибка, хоть entryComponents прописал

Comment: DialogContentExampleDialog используется внутри ModalModule или снаружи?

Comment: DialogContentExampleDialog  используется внутри, DiakigContentExample по клику вызывает DialogContentExampleDialog, в котором контент модалки расписан

Comment: @ЭдуардКозлов покажи мне пример в документации по которому ты это делаешь? что такое `bootstrap: [DialogContentExample]`? и создай нормальный пример на stackblitz, за картинку поставлю минус